# oracle DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, exception, database-migration, plpgsql

is there any Postgres replacement for exception DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX? I'm  migrating a database from Oracle to PostgreSQL.

my query example:

```
EXCEPTION
            WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX
            THEN
               BEGIN
                  UPDATE BTPN_INS_PEOPLE_EXT
                     SET EFFECTIVE_END_DATE = NULL,
                         REGISTER_DATE = l_dMakerDate,
                         PASSPORT_NO = l_vPassportNo,
                         FAMILY_CARD_NO = l_vFamilyCardNo,
                         UPDATE_BY = i_vUSER_ID,
                         UPDATE_ON = SYSDATE,
                         RECORD_FLAG = 'U'
                   WHERE     PERSON_ID = l_nMainPersonId
                         AND EFFECTIVE_START_DATE = TRUNC (SYSDATE);

                  SELECT INTERNALID
                    INTO l_nPeopleExtId
                    FROM BTPN_INS_PEOPLE_EXT
                   WHERE     PERSON_ID = l_nMainPersonId
                         AND EFFECTIVE_START_DATE = TRUNC (SYSDATE)
                         AND EFFECTIVE_END_DATE IS NULL
                         AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: Are you looking for `unique_violation`?

Comment: No need to catch an exception in Postgre**s**. Use `insert ... on conflict (...) do update ...` instead

Comment: You also don't need the SELECT after the UPDATE. In Postgres you can use `update ... returning .. into`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comment,

The replacement of the `DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX` (In oracle) is `unique_violation` in PostgreSQL.

It is mentioned in the Error codes of the PostgreSQL documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html)